# How do I save data in a text file python

Tags: python

So I am making a simple randomized number game, and I want to save the players High Score even after the program is shut down and ran again. I want the computer to be able to ask the player their name, search through the database of names in a text file, and pull up their high score. Then if their name is not there, create a name in the database. I am unsure on how to do that. I am a noob programmer and this is my second program. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the Code for the random number game:

```
import random
import time

def getscore():
    score = 0
    return score
    print(score)


def main(score):
    number = random.randrange(1,5+1)
    print("Your score is %s") %(score)
    print("Please enter a number between 1 and 5")

    user_number = int(raw_input(""))

    if user_number == number:
        print("Congrats!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Your number was %d, the computers number was also %d!") %(user_number,number)
        score = score + 10
        main(score)

    elif user_number != number:
        print("Sorry")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Your number was %d, but the computers was %d.") %(user_number, number)
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Your total score was %d") %(score)
        time.sleep(2)
        getscore()

score = getscore()
main(score)
main(score)
```

EDIT:
I am trying this and it seems to be working, except, when I try to replace the string with a variable, it gives an error:

```
def writehs():
    name = raw_input("Please enter your name")
    a = open('scores.txt', 'w')
    a.write(name: 05)
    a.close()

def readhs():
    f = open("test.txt", "r")
writehs()
readhs()
```

Comment: Pickle can store/retreive variables in a file. JSON can also do this.

Comment: how exactly do you use 'pickle'

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html).

Comment: `import pickle` then `f = open('filename', 'w')`, then create an object with all the data you want to store, then use `pickle.dump(obj, f)`. Never use the words `file` or `object` as a python variable name.  From: http://python.about.com/od/pythonstandardlibrary/a/pickle_intro.htm

Comment: JSON is much more user friendly in my opinion.

Answer (score 13):

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write(getscore())
```

Using `with` like this is the preferred way to work with files because it automatically handles file closure, even through exceptions.

Also, remember to fix your `getscore()` method so it doesn't always return 0. If you want it to `print` the score as well, put the `print` statement before the `return`.

Answer (score 9):

In order to write a file using python do the following:

```
file2write=open("filename",'w')
file2write.write("here goes the data")
file2write.close()
```

If you want to read or append the file just change 'w' for 'r' or 'a' respectively

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should ask your question clearly enough for others to understand.To add a text into text file you could always use the `open` built-in function.Do it like this.

```
>>> a = open('test.txt', 'w')
>>> a.write('theunixdisaster\t 05')
>>> a.close()
```

Thats all.If need further help try this website.
http://www.afterhoursprogramming.com/tutorial/Python/Writing-to-Files/

You could also use a for loop for the game to print all the scores.
Try this one on your own.It would rather be fun.

**THE RECOMENDED WAY**

Well as if the recommended way use it like this:

```
>>> with open('test.txt', 'w') as a:
        a.write('theunixdisaster\t 05')
```

With this its certain that the file would close.

**With variables**

```
>>> name = sempron
>>> with open('test.txt', 'w') as a:
        a.write('%s: 05' % name)
```

Now try calling it.Well I use `python 3.4.2`.So, if you get into errors, try to check if there is any difference in the string formatting with the python version that you use.

Comment: Ok, sorry my question was not clear enough, Ill try the for loop. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can i replace the 'theunixdisaster' with a variable name?

Comment: If you could wait a minute I would search the web give a proper answer to that.

Comment: Yes you could.First write the first line of my code.Then set a variable `b` to `theunixdisaster`.Then carry the other lines in my code.Don't forget to replace the 'theunixdisaster' in line two with the variable `b`.

Comment: Thank You So Much you have been really helpful!

Comment: Don't mention it. I got an 8th standard science examination.So if there is any help that I could do I'll try it in the evening.

Comment: Please note that opening a file without the `with` construction is no longer the recommended way to work with files.

Comment: I didn't use the with, did I ?

Comment: @theunixdisaster TigerHawk said opening a file without the with is no longer recommended way.

Comment: Oops my bad.But it worked in the 3.4.2 version.Any way sorry @TigerhawkT3 and thank you user3184082

Comment: It works, but the `with` construction is recommended because it is guaranteed to close the file.

Comment: @theunixdisaster when I try to replace 'theunixdisaster', it does not work. I will edit the main post and give the code

Comment: @user3184082 Try string formatting.I'll show it in my answer.

Comment: @theunixdisaster ok, I did it a different way, thanks